# HTML contact form

Tags: php, html, css

I just put contact form in HTML one page site, but after I add contact code to HTML index file, when I open my site my page loads not on top banner, logo etc., but on contact form.

```html
<!-- contact pradzia -->
<form id="contact" action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Jūsų vardas" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Jūsų el. pašto adresas" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Jūsų tel. nr." type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Tema" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea placeholder="Rašykite žinute čia..." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Siųsti</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- contact pabaiga -->
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly share full page html code instead of only contact form html.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/src/app.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Gintaro drožyba</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/> <!-- ikonele -->
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigacija -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo ir responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                 Gintaro drožyba
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar linkai -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Pagrindinis</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Galerija</a>
                    </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Darbai <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
       <li><a href="#">Paveikslai</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Skulptūros</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Baldai</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Suvenyrai</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kita</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

 <!-- baneris -->
 <div class="jumbotron feature">
  <div class="container">
   <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer"></span> Gintaro Černiaus drožyba</h1>
   <p>Medžio darbai, drožyba, mediniai baldai, paveikslai, skulptūros</p>
   <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Plačiau</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>


    <!-- heading -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">Ilgametė patirtis</h1>
                <p class="lead text-center">Kažkokia informacija. Pasirinkite:</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- darbai -->
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row promo">
         <a href="#">
    <div class="col-md-4 promo-item item-1">
     <h3>
      Galerija
     </h3>
    </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
    <div class="col-md-4 promo-item item-2">
     <h3>
      Kontaktai
     </h3>
    </div>
            </a>
   
   <a href="#">
    <div class="col-md-4 promo-item item-3">
     <h3>
      Užsakymas
     </h3>
    </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

 <!-- parduodami darbai -->
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">Padaryti darbai pardavimui</h1>
  <div class="row">
  
   <!-- darbas 1 -->
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail featured-product">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/foto1.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
     <div class="caption">
      <h3>Paveikslas</h3>
      <p>Kažkoks tekstas</p>
      <p class="price">95.99 EUR</p>

      <!-- mygtukas bootstrap -->
      <div class="input-group">
       <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
         Pridėti į krepšelį
        </button>
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!-- darbas 2 -->
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail featured-product">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/foto2.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
     <div class="caption">
      <h3>Paveikslas 2</h3>
      <p>Kažkoks tekstas</p>
      <p class="price"><s>85.95 EUR</s>65.95 EUR</p>

      <!-- mygtukas bootstrap -->
      <div class="input-group">
       <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
         Pridėti į krepšelį
        </button>
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!-- darbas 3 -->
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail featured-product">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/foto3.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
     <div class="caption">
      <h3>Paveikslas 3</h3>
      <p>Kažkoks tekstas</p>
      <p class="price">145.99 EUR</p>

      <!-- mygtukas bootstrap -->
      <div class="input-group">
       <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
         Pridėti į krepšelį
        </button>
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!-- darbas 4 -->
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail featured-product">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/foto3.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
     <div class="caption">
      <h3>Paveikslas 3</h3>
      <p>Kažkoks tekstas</p>
      <p class="price">199.99 EUR</p>

      <!-- mygtukas bootstrap -->
      <div class="input-group">
       <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
         Pridėti į krepšelį
        </button>
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
 
 
 <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="container"> 
  <h1>Apie mane</h1>
        <p class="lead">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
  <img class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" src="images/service.jpg" alt="">
 </div><!--/.container--> 
            <!-- contact pradzia -->
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Jūsų vardas" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Jūsų el. pašto adresas" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Jūsų tel. nr." type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Tema" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Rašykite žinute čia..." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Siųsti</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
         <!-- contact pabaiga -->
  
 <!-- footeris -->
 <footer>
 
  <h1 class="text-center">Mane rasite</h1>
  <!-- Map -->
   <script id="map" src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyA4G64jXEiyPLOA1XKXDkvl901-khuxrao'></script><div style='overflow:hidden;height:423px;width:1401px;'><div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:423px;width:1401px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <a href='https://embedmaps.net'>add google map</a> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=0884e686c4548d57daed57d5f4148e6ad91ea399'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:17,center:new google.maps.LatLng(55.3386064,26.155018400000017),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(55.3386064,26.155018400000017)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Mane rasite</strong><br>Turistų g. 20<br>30136 Ignalina<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12 footer-info-item text-center">
      <h2>Susisiekite</h2>
      <p class="lead"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span> +370 672 07463</p>
                        <p class="lead"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> drozyba@gmail.com</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  <!-- Footer Links -->
  <div class="footer-info">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-info-item">
      <h3>Informacija</h3>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
       <li><a href="#">Apie mane</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Galerija</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Kontaktai</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paslaugos</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-info-item">
      <h3>My Account</h3>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
       <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">View Cart</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">My Wishlist</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Track My Order</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      </ul> 
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-info-item">
      <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Newsletter</h3>
      <p>Sign up for exclusive offers.</p>
      <div class="input-group">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
         Subscribe!
        </button>
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
   </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div>
        
        <!-- Copyright -->
        <div class="small-print">
         <div class="container">
          <p>Copyright &copy; drozyba.lt 2017 </p>
         </div>
        </div>
        
 </footer>

 
    <!-- jQuery pirmas :) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrapo JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- IE10 viewport failas -->
 <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the autofocus attribute form your first input (: